# How do I block data:image images in a google web search?

Tags: image, google-search, adblock

I'm trying to block the images Google gives during a regular web search with a adblock plus filter. I have tried ##div[id="iur"] and ##img[src^="data:image"] (along with other things I can't remember).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: Needed to disabled the "Allow some non-intrusive advertising"

Long Answer: I added the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/ add-on in ff and it gave me this filter: google.com###iur this too didn't work till I disabled the "Allow some non-intrusive advertising" as I found posted [here](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=27735&p=116307&hilit=google+overrides#p116307) that this is done last and cancels some of the filterers previously set.

As it turns out  ##div[id="iur"] and ##img[src^="data:image"] both also work.